# Comparison of Hilbert space tensor product and wedge product

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, geometric-algebras

For Hilbert Spaces:

$$(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)\otimes (|0\rangle + |1\rangle) = |00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle.$$

where all results are column vectors

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &=& \langle 00|01\rangle, \\ 
&=& \langle 00|10\rangle, \\
&=& \langle 00|11\rangle,
\end{eqnarray*}

etc. But for Geometric Algebra, the geometric product results in all orthogonal bivectors

$$(a_0 + a_1)*(b_0+b_1) = a_0\wedge b_0 + a_0\wedge b_1 + a_1\wedge b_0 + a_1\wedge b_1.$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &=& \langle a_0\wedge b_0,a_0\wedge b_1\rangle, \\
&=& \langle a_0\wedge b_0,a_1\wedge b_0\rangle, \\
&=& \langle a_0\wedge b_0,a_1\wedge b_1\rangle,
\end{eqnarray*}

etc. The questions is: Where did the bivectors go in the Hilbert space tensor product? this leads to different results for bell and magic states between the two representations.

Comment: Please don't sneak singles ads into titles

Comment: If you're going to post high-level mathematics, you *really* need to learn $\LaTeX$ (or if you already know it, you need to implement it here). It makes it much easier for others to understand your point if it's written properly.

Comment: One thing to note is that tensor products are really like multiplication of vectors. However bivectors *involve* multiplication but are antisymmetric - tensor products need not be. The point of bivectors and multivectors in general is to compute areas, volumes and such. Particularly, $u\wedge v = uv - vu$ (assuming you can make sense of the product of two vectors). Whereas the tensor product would be more like $u\otimes v = uv$. Furthermore, bivectors live in the original space of interest whereas tensor products live in a larger Hilbert space.. They are very different.

Comment: @rschwieb At least it said "deeply", not "intimately".

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my question with latex. A small point, is the last equations 0 = etc are inner products (the operator is a "." in geomatric algebra not the braket brackets.

Comment: my purpose for putting this question here is to start a dialogue about this topic. Cameron's answer is true, but my Ph.D. research showed that it is possible to express entangled bell states using geometric algebra. From this understanding, $$ |00\rangle + |11\rangle $$ is equivalent to $$ a_0\wedge b_0 + a_1\wedge b_1$$ So the key question is: there is a difference in the two representation in that the Hilbert space bell operator is reversible and Geometric algebra bell operators is irreversible due to multiplicative cancellation. Is there a better forum to discuss this topic?

Comment: I'm thinking your question may just be too specific.  There aren't that many people currently studying/ using geometric algebra, so I'd guess that the probability of you finding someone who both understands GA and quantum information theory is fairly slim.  I'm not saying you shouldn't ask, I just don't know that you can realistically expect an answer.  If you'd like recommendations of other sites you could try, how about [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/), [Phys.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), or [Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/).

Comment: You might also try calling it Clifford algebra because that's what most physicists would call GA.